# onPageFinished Does Not Fire On Specific Page

Tags: android, webview

I have an application that I'm showing webpages through webview. But on one page progress dialog does not dismiss on page finished loading. This is the php code of that page.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

//hesap php ye verilen link restoran adi degiskenini de icermeli
$restadi = $_GET["restadi"];
//Toplam deger sifirlaniyor
$uruntotal = 0;
echo '<html>';
echo '<head>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sepet.css">';
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
echo '</head>';
echo "<table class='hesap'>";

//hesap oturumundaki her eleman icin ayri sorgu olusturuluyor
foreach($_SESSION['hesap'] as $urunid => $urunsayi) {
// $urunid urunun veritabanindaki kodu $urunsayi da siparisteki sayisi
// $urunid bilgisi ile veritabanindan urun adi ve fiyati aliniyor
$restadi = mysql_real_escape_string($restadi);
$urunid = mysql_real_escape_string($urunid);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $restadi WHERE urunid=$urunid");
$db = mysql_fetch_array( $data );


//siparisin toplam fiyati hesaplaniyor
$urunfiyat = $db['urunfiyat'] * $urunsayi;
$uruntotal = $urunfiyat + $uruntotal; 
//veriler tablo halinde ekrana basiliyor
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="urunadi">'.$db['urunadi'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="urunfiyat">'.$urunfiyat.' TL</td>';
echo '</tr>';
};
echo '</table>';
//toplam ayri tabloya yaziliyor
echo '<table style="float: right;" border="5px">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Toplam</td>';
echo '<td class="urunfiyat">'.$uruntotal.' TL</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';

echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
?>
```

PS: I don't want to use de depreciated Picture Listener. And this situation does not related to use of sessions. Because this is not the only page that uses sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. onpagefinished actually fires so that's not the problem. This happens when you use redirection in your php file. Just add some delay to your php location and problem goes away.